# unable to get metadate title on hebrew (get it on gibberish)

Tags: java, android, url, stream, hebrew

I'm developing android applications

When doing a code to get streaming title "now loading" i unable to recieve the title on hebrew

but i recieved him  on gibberish

if someone can help me with this i will be a greatful
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwE9P.jpg)

```
    @Override
    protected IcyStreamMeta doInBackground(URL... urls)
    {
        try
        {
            streamMeta.refreshMeta();
            Log.e("Retrieving MetaData","Refreshed Metadata");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(MetadataTask2.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
        }
        return streamMeta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(IcyStreamMeta result)
    {
        try
        {
            title_artist=streamMeta.getTitle();
            Log.e("Retrieved title_artist", title_artist);
            if(title_artist.length()>0)
            {
                textView.setText(title_artist);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(MetadataTask2.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        try {
            streamMeta.refreshMeta();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            String title_artist=streamMeta.getTitle();
            Log.i("ARTIST TITLE", title_artist);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: The requirements to add code and avoid pastebin links are there for a reason. Circumventing them will just get your question closed. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of linking to a lot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [IcyMetaData](https://github.com/figadore/radio-presets-widget/blob/master/src/com/radiopirate/android/service/IcyStreamMeta.java) simply casts raw  bytes to `char` (effectively doing ISO-8859-1 encoding instead of using detecting whatever the server sends) at [line 149](https://github.com/figadore/radio-presets-widget/blob/master/src/com/radiopirate/android/service/IcyStreamMeta.java#L149):

```
metaData.append((char) b);
```

I don't see a way to fix this without patching/fixing the `IcyMetaData` class.

Comment: so i have to change this class?

Comment: Yes, it probably needs to wrap the `InputStream` in an `InputStreamReader` and provide the correct encoding. *Either* that encoding is well-specified (probably UTF-8), or communicated via a HTTP header, but I don't know which one it is here.